# Syntax explanation of LocaleResolver and LocaleChangeInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

1)I understand that the syntax for CookieLocaleResolver is as follows:

```
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
<property name="cookieName" value="clientlanguage"/>
```

What I understand is this resolver searches for all cookies in the request whose value might match a locale ..so property name is set as "Cookie Name" but why is the value also set ..is it that we are replacing the locale value in the respective cookie by this.
  2)Is it possible to change the locale without sing the LocaleChangeInterceptor?
3)In SessionLocaleResolver what does the following property signify:

```
<property name="defaultName" value="clientlanguage"/>
```

and how does the SessionLocale work?

Answer (score 0):

In `CookieLocaleResolver` you need to specify the name of the cookie. It searches for a specific cookie, not for any cookie containing locale-like value. In your example the cookie will be named `clientlanguage`.

`SessionLocaleResolver` stores the client locale in user session. There is no property `defaultName` on this bean. However there is `defaultLocale` property (similar property is also on `CookieLocaleResolver`), where you can set what should be the default locale if the user didn't explicitly switch to a different one.

Ad. changing locale - you can change locale just by calling `localeResolver.setLocale(...)`. That is what `LocaleChangeInterceptor` is doing.